# Left Justify a String in C# with the length dynamically given

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a Left Justify Function such as:

```
private static string LeftJustify(string field, int len)
{
    string retVal = string.empty;

    ///todo:

   return retVal;

}
```

can you help me put the logic in the function?

Comment: Strings are just strings... they don't contain any formatting/style information by themselves. Are you writing some kind of text formatter/editor?

Comment: @user: BTW, there is no such thing as "C#.NET". It's just "C#".

Comment: Please explain, what you mean bei 'justify'. It's not clear, what you want to achieve. Other than that - have a look at C#'s TrimStart() and PadLeft()

Comment: Can you provide example inputs and outputs? I don't quite know what _you_ mean by "Left Justify".

Comment: sorry I am trying to do left pad with spaces actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just trying to pad the string, you can use [String.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx) directly:

```
private static string LeftJustify(string field, int len)
{
    return field.PadRight(len);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From [C# Examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/):

> To align string to the right or to the left use static method `String.Format`. To align string to the left (spaces on the right) use formatting pat[t]ern with comma (,) followed by a negative number of characters: `String.Format("{0,–10}", text)`. To right alignment use a positive number: `{0,10}`

C#:

```
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("First Name | Last Name  |   Age");
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Bill", "Gates", 51));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Edna", "Parker", 114));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Johnny", "Depp", 44));
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
```

Output:

```
 -------------------------------
 First Name | Last Name  |   Age
 -------------------------------
 Bill       | Gates      |    51
 Edna       | Parker     |   114
 Johnny     | Depp       |    44
 -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string functions [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx) or [`PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx).

These will add spaces to a string, as many as needed.

Comment: No example given and `PadLeft` and `PadRight` are not that useful because of the `totalWidth` argument. So you'll get into a situation where you'll not have enough padding on the left side because you are overflowing your width requirement for the line (one use case). In the case where you just want to add padding to a line (the other use case), they are mildly inconvenient (i.e. `someString.PadLeft(' ', someString.Length + paddingWidth);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use PadLeft explicitly

or use String.Format like this (which does most of the math)

`String.Format("|{0,-10}|", field)`
Output : if field="Fred"

```
|      Fred|
```

Comment: this is right justify. I want to left justify. Anyways I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set length you want to maintain, and the string length varies, you could

while (retval.length < 21)
{ retval = " " + retval}

This would left pad the string until it is 20 characters long.

Comment: updated code - lesson learned - don't answer posts in a hurry or without verifying your code

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments you want to pad left with spaces. `PadLeft()` works for this, but you need to be aware of the 'totalWidth' parameter:

```
var s = "some text";
int paddingWidth = 4;

// example for no limit on line width
s.PadLeft(s.Length + paddingWidth, ' '); // results in "    someText"
```

But if there is a limit on the allowed line length, it will produce the wrong output (i.e. not pad with the desired amount of characters) and no error. You can even specify a `totalWidth` that is less than the total source string length.

If you want to always prepend a fixed amount of spaces, you can use this as well:

```
var padding = new StringBuilder();
padding.Append(' ', 5); // replace 5 with what's useful.
var result = padding + someString;
```

An alternative to spaces is tabulator characters, which will indent by some amount - often 4 spaces (depending on the context). That could be achieved by:

```
padding.Append('\t', count);
```

And so forth.
You could put the logic for the padding in an extra method or extension method.
Note, I didn't use the `StringBuilder` for efficiency reasons here. It is just convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add some parameter validation but this should work.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    static readonly char[] _whiteSpaceCharacters;

    static Extensions()
    {
        var r = new List<char>();
        for (char c = char.MinValue; c < char.MaxValue; c++)
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                r.Add(c);
        _whiteSpaceCharacters = r.ToArray();
    }

    public static string LeftJustify(this string value)
    {
        return value.LeftJustify(4);
    }

    public static string LeftJustify(this string value, int length)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var sr = new StringReader(value))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(
                    line
                    .TrimStart(_whiteSpaceCharacters)
                    .PadLeft(length, ' ')
                );
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
     Line 1
         Line 2     
             Line 3
 Line 4
```

**Output**

```
     Line 1
     Line 2     
     Line 3
     Line 4
```