# How to increment String.Format item in a loop?

Tags: c#

I have a task:
there is a text in a txt file, and I need to write each word of an each line of the text into fixed position in another text file.

For example, we have a line: "Hello, my name is Bob"

In a text file:
First word of the line |Second word |Third word |Fourth word |Fifth word etc
__________________Hello__________my________name__________is______Bob

In a file there would not be the headers and underscore, they are just for explanation.

I have an idea to accomplish this:

```
using(var smth = File.CreateText(smth1))
{
string[] splittedLine = {"Hello,", "my", "name", "is", "Bob"};
int x = LengthOfTheLongestWordInTheText;
for(int i = 0; i < splittedLine.Length; i++)
{ smth.WriteLine(String.Format("{i,x}", splittedLine[i]"))//PseudoCode;The question
}
```

The questionable situation is marked by the comment line - is there a way to increment the `{i,x}` ? I mean that for every word in the string, the `{i,x}` would be different: for a first word it would be `{0,x}`, for the 2nd - `{1,x}` and so on, so the words would be printted in corresponding places.

Were looking for an answer without luck.
Thank you for help.

Comment: The simplest way is probably to use [`String.PadRight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_PadRight_System_Int32_) or `String.PadLeft` inside the loop. You can also use `new String(' ', n)` to repeat the space character `n` times. See also: [Pad left or right with string.format (not padleft or padright) with arbitrary string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541098/69809) or [Left Justify a String in C# with the length dynamically given](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5569994/69809).

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
string[] splittedLine = { "Hello,", "my", "name", "is", "Bob" };
for(var i = 0; i < splittedLine.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"{splittedLine[i]}");
}
```

Just a demo on how to achieve what you want, 
the syntax $"{varName}" converts varName to string and you have the freedom to input array indexes.
It was introduced in C# 6 and is named [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: I do not see how that could be helpful for my situation

Comment: From what i understood from question, you are looking for a way to automate string.format so dont have to write {0},{1}, etc, this code shows a sample on how  to do that.